# Is it a good idea to never delete branches from the remote repository?

Tags: git, github

We are using Gitflow for all developments but we never set upstreams for feature branches and Gitflow removes our local branches when we execute the finish command. There is only three of us and usually we work off of the develop branch which is upstreamed to track our develop branch on the remote repository.

#### 2 Questions?

1. Should we make all our feature branches available on the remote repository?
2. Is it a good practice to never delete branches from the remote repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious to see the group's thoughts on this, but I'm of the opinion that I never want to lose data. I still find myself digging through SVN commits from 10 years ago to see where my head was, and finding little ideas I forgot about that I want to bring to life again with my new, more powerful programmer brain. Also, in the off-chance that our product becomes something really famous, I'd like to have the record of what went into the creation of it, for posterity. The commits themselves are so cheap to store, and that space is only getting cheaper.

That said, if your branches are being merged back in, deleting them is only removing pointers; the commits are being held in place forever by the merge commits. The merge commit by default has the name of the branch that was merged back in, so you can still figure out what the now nameless branch was originally called. This seems the best of both worlds to me. I'm not a big fan of squashed commits, though I'm open to explanations as to why I should be.